# backbonejs router first query parameter

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I am trying to add a query parameter as the first parameter in backbonejs route but no luck.

Below is my router config.

```
TabsRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "tab/:tabname": "goToTab",
        "*default": "defaultTab"
    },

    goToTab: function(tabName) {
        view.renderTab(tabName);
    },

    defaultTab: function() {
        view.renderTab('markets');
    }
});
tabsRouter = new TabsRouter();
```

The above code works fine and i can access the routes like baseurl/#tab/personal but i want something baseurl/#personal, I don't want to start with tab. I have tried ":tabname" route but its not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try create different paths for each tab?

Comment: This should work but isn't there any generic way to achieve this instead of hardcoding the route for each tab?

Comment: @SebastianLorenzo Your suggestion solved the problem for me. If you can answer the question then i will accept your answer as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of best way that you can solve your trouble is using different paths for each tab.

Following your code, it would be:

```
TabsRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "tab/first-tab": "firstTabView",
        "tab/second-tab": "secondTabView",
        "tab/third-tab": "thirdTabView",
        "*default": "defaultTab"
    },

    firstTabView: function() {
        view.renderFirstTab();
    },
    secondTabView: function() {
        view.renderSecondTab();
    },
    thirdTabView: function() {
        view.renderThirdTab();
    },
    defaultTab: function() {
        view.renderDefault();
    }
});
tabsRouter = new TabsRouter();
```

Hope it helps you.